# android open edittext on touch outside the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am trying this for 2 days now and i didn't manage to quite make it work. I want when the user clicks the screen outside the edittext to call the edittext, i manage to open the keyboard but you have to click the edittext if you want to write, and this makes the keyboard close and the reopen...

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            } else {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}
```

Comment: Calling `requestFocus()`on the editText does not work?

Comment: i tried but if i call requestFocus() the only difference is that i have to double tap to show the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a matter of calling requestFocus() on your EditText at the end.

Comment: i tried but if i call requestFocus() the only difference is that i have to double tap to show the keyboard